# Site em Real-time com Node.JS

Tags: javascript, mysql, html5, node.js, express.js

Fala pessoal, alguém pode me ajudar nessa…

Desenvolvi um site totalmente dinâmico com banco de dados MySQL, ou seja, todos os principais elementos da página principal estão vindo do banco de dados, faço isso utilizando Node.JS, Express e MySQL.

O problema é que após alterar algo no banco de dados, mesmo atualizando a página (F5) as informações da tela não mudam. A mudança só reflete na página seu eu reiniciar o serviço “nodemon app.js” pelo CMD.

Já pesquisei bastante sobre o assunto e cheguei no Socket.io, até consegui iniciar ele aqui na minha aplicação, mas não estou conseguindo empregar ele na atualização das consultas ao MySQL.

Vejam os principais trechos da estrutura do meu código relacionados a este tema, por favor, me ajudem:

Trecho do arquivo **app.js**

```
const express = require('express');
var http = require('http');
var socket = require('socket.io');

var app = express();
var http = http.Server(app);
var io = socket(http);

var port = 3000;
io.on('connection', function (io) {
http.listen(port, () => {
    console.log('Em execução');
    console.log('Endereço do site : localhost:', port);
});

//Aqui está minha rota onde faço as consultas
const rotas = require('./routes/rotas')(io);
app.use('/', rotas);
```

Até aqui tudo ok.

Vamos agora para o arquivo da rota:
Trecho do arquivo **rotas.js**

```
module.exports = (io) => {//Aqui recebo o socket.io lá do app.js

var express = require('express');
var rotas = express.Router();

const { pageSite } = require('../controller/site/site.js'(io); //Aqui passo o socket.io para o site.js
rotas.get('/', pageSite); //localhost:3000 (rota da página principal)

return rotas;
};
```

Até aqui tudo ok.

Vamos agora para o arquivo que faz o render da página principal do site:
Trecho do arquivo **site.js**

```
//Aqui importo o site-model onde tem minhas consultas SQL
const funcao = require('./site-model');

//Aqui pego o resultado da consulta e gravo na variável section1
let section1;
(async function () {
   section1 = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(await funcao.getSection1_Title));
})()

//Aqui passo os dados da variável section1 como parâmetro para o render da página
module.exports = (io) => {
   return {
      pageSite: (req, res, next) => {
         res.render('./site/index', {
             DTSection1: section1
         });
      },
   };
}
```

Até aqui tudo ok.

Vamos agora para o arquivo que faz as consultas utilizadas pelo render:
Trecho do arquivo **site-model.js**

```
//Função para consuoltar no banco
function select(query) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        conn.query(query, function (err, rows, fields) {
            if (err) return reject(err)
            resolve(rows);
        });
    });
}
module.exports = {
getSection1: (async function () {
        const result = await select('SELECT * FROM tb_section1 ORDER BY cod DESC');
        return result;
    })(),
}
```

Até aqui tudo ok.

Esta tudo funcionando perfeitamente, sempre que atualizo algo no BD ele reflete na página **desde que eu reinicie o serviço node no CMD**.

AJUDA: Só que preciso que os dados se atualizem na página **quando eu der “F5” na página**.

Penso que ao ao atualizar a página o socket.io deveria reprocessar a consulta ao BD regravando o retorno novo na variável “section1” do arquivo site.js, **mas como fazer isso?**

Observação: Reforço que no render da página passo 22 variáveis que receberam 22 consultas vindas de 22 tabelas diferentes.

Comment: Não vejo porque precisas do SocketsIO, o problema que descreves não precisa de Sockets para resolver. Podes explicar melhor uma das rotas que não estava a atualizar e todo o código que isso corre?

Comment: Pra mim o problema é que vc utilizar promisses, se vc utilizar apenas chamadas ao servidor sem promise, vc resolve o seu problema, as coisas voltam a serem atualizadas apenas com o f5.

Answer (score 1):

Não reflete ao atualizar a pagina pq você está pegando os dados quando a app inicia.
veja:

```
// isso é executado apenas uma vez, assim que o arquivo é importado
let section1;
(async function () {
   section1 = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(await funcao.getSection1_Title));
})()

// sempre que esse rota e chamada vc pega o valor que esta em memoria
module.exports = (io) => {
   return {
      pageSite: (req, res, next) => {
         res.render('./site/index', {
             DTSection1: section1
         });
      },
   };
}
```

para que funciona corretamento o codigo deveria ser assim:

```
// ...
function getSection1_Title() {
        return select('SELECT * FROM tb_section1 ORDER BY cod DESC');
}

// ...

module.exports = (io) => {
   return {
      pageSite: async (req, res, next) => {
         res.render('./site/index', {
             DTSection1: await getSection1_Title()
         });
      },
   };
}
```

Pelo que note por algum motivo vc esta usando funcões auto invocadas: `(() => {})()`
Não sei pq vc esta fazendo isso, não faz o menor sentido usar nesse contexto encontra.

Comment: Fala Galera, tentei todas as possibilidades sugeridas e ainda sem sucesso, sou novo na programação WEB e estou apanhando um pouco, coloquei o código fonte no 4Shared, querem dar uma olhada se conseguem resolver por favor: https://www.4shared.com/zip/yLetNq92iq/CCF.html

Comment: @FabioEduardoArgenton a resposta do Matheus aponta para falhas no conhecimento de encadeamento de código assíncrono. Era isso que te estava a indicar no meu comentário (que nem respondeste). Compreendeste a maneira de pensar que o Matheus referiu?

Comment: Pessoal, obrigado a todos, agradeço mesmo a ajuda, mas consegui resolver, mative o mesmo código e só acrescentei um trecho antes do render, vejam:

pageSite: (req, res, next) => {
      //Esse trecho aqui foi a solução 
      conn.query('SELECT * FROM section_1_title ORDER BY cod DESC LIMIT 1', function (err, rows, fields) {
        if (err) throw err;
        section1 = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(rows));//Aqui regrava a nova consulta
      });

Obs: Alguem fechou o tópico agora não consigo postar a solução completa.